# Почему значение в списке [0, 0] == []?

Tags: python

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(arr):
    list1 = [] 
    list2 = []
    for i in arr:
        if i > 0:
            list1.append(i)
        else:
            list2.append(i)    
    list3 = list([len(list1), sum(list2)])
    if list3:
        return list3
```

Валидатор не засчитывает решение, ошибкой считает **[0, 0] should equal []**
и наоборот **[] should equal [0, 0]**. Как решить эту проблему?

Given an array of integers.

Return an array, where the first element is the count of positives numbers and the second element is sum of negative numbers. 0 is neither positive nor negative.
If the input is an empty array or is null, return an empty array.

Example:
For input [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15], you should return [10, -65].

Comment: приведите для начала точный текст задания, пожалуйста, а не что возвращает ваша функция. Валидатор относительно него проверяет.

Comment: готово, и почему нельзя создать 2 пустых списка через 1 строку? с переменными это возможно a, b = 2 почему со списком нельзя? lst1, lst2 = []

Comment: Можно, вот так: a = b = []. Но они будут ссылаться на один и тот же массив, это может привести к проблемам. Или вот так: a, b = [], []. Чтобы были разные списки.

Comment: вот это уже интересней, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы нарушили условие. Написано же: "If the input is an empty array or is null, return an empty array." Т.е. при [] на входе, он же и на выходе должен быть. Проверьте код ниже на валидаторе, я добавил условие проверки (при `None` вообще ваш код давал ошибку).

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(arr):
    if arr == [] or arr == None:
        return []
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for i in arr:
        if i > 0:
            list1.append(i)
        else:
            list2.append(i)
    list3 = list([len(list1), sum(list2)])
    if list3:
        return list3
```

Comment: Excellent Сергей :) снова раз выручили

Comment: 1-ой строкой: return [len([x for x in arr if x > 0])] + [sum(y for y in arr if y < 0)] if arr else []